# woocommerce breadcrumb missing shop link

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I have a WordPress site that uses woocommerce (in internal page), my URL structure for shop page as follow:

**mysite/shop/**

breadcrumb on woocommerce pages show only home link like :
You are here: Home

and my product page url:

**Mysite/product-category/category_name/**

my shop page breadcrumb show as follow:

```
You are here: Home
```

also my category page breadcrumb show as follow:

```
You are here: Home
```

I need to make it show as :

You are here: Home / shopping / category_name

I checked permalinks options but it seems OK .
I checked breadcrumb.php template file it seems that it consider that shop () page is the home page of my site.

How can I fix this , should i edit breadcrumb.php or there is an error in my settings? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that breadcrumb code was in header.php of my courture theme folder and author of that theme didn't write code for products or product category pages so I added

```
elseif (is_single() && get_post_type() == 'product'){   
$posts_page_id = get_option('page_for_posts');
$posts_page_url = get_permalink($posts_page_id); 
echo '<li>';$bar = "shopping";
if(get_option_tree('blog_name', '', false))
/*$bar=get_option_tree('blog_name', '', false);*/ 
echo "<a href=".home_url()."/shopping/>$bar</a></li>";
echo "<li>";
the_title();
echo"</li>";
}
```

and for product category page

```
if (is_tax()) { 
$posts_page_id = get_option('page_for_posts');
$posts_page_url = get_permalink($posts_page_id); 
echo '<li>';$bar = "Shopping";
if(get_option_tree('blog_name', '', false)) 
echo "<a href=".home_url()."/shopping/>$bar</a> > </li>" ; 
echo "<li>"; 
woocommerce_page_title(); 
echo"</li>";}
```

I commented the line that get the blog_name because I use custom page for my shop not the woocommerce default one . I don't know if there is another way to do this but I notice that most code in this theme not really professional even in widget css it was a bad choice.

Answer (score 19):

For anyone who stumbles on this in 2019, there is a much easier way to add an item after the "Home" breadcrumb, if you don't want to change your permalinks or edit theme files. This may not be a perfect solution, but it worked for me.

The WC_Breadcrumb class filters the breadcrumbs before it returns them, and we can hook in and modify the array. The $crumbs array is just an array of [ [title, url], [title, url] ]

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', function($crumbs, $Breadcrumb){
        $shop_page_id = wc_get_page_id('shop'); //Get the shop page ID
        if($shop_page_id > 0 && !is_shop()) { //Check we got an ID (shop page is set). Added check for is_shop to prevent Home / Shop / Shop as suggested in comments
            $new_breadcrumb = [
                _x( 'Shop', 'breadcrumb', 'woocommerce' ), //Title
                get_permalink(wc_get_page_id('shop')) // URL
            ];
            array_splice($crumbs, 1, 0, [$new_breadcrumb]); //Insert a new breadcrumb after the 'Home' crumb
        }
        return $crumbs;
    }, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: You might want to add `if (!is_shop())` so it doesn't put on the Shop page home / shop / shop

Comment: Great thinking, thanks! I had just come across that in the project I'm (still) working on. Thank you - updated answer.

Comment: you can change your breadcrumb title to use `get_the_title($shop_page_id)` as not everyone uses "Shop" as the shop page. Also, get_permalink can be changed to use `get_permalink($shop_page_id)` as you already have a variable set with the shop page ID.

Answer (score 11):

I was debugging this and unfortunatelly Woocommerce (ver. 2.3.8) doesn't use any hooks to directly adjust the breadcrumbs array. So if you want to modify the breadcrumbs shown without changing the permalinks structure, best is to copy the breadcrumbs template file from plugin ( `/woocommerce/templates/global/breadcrumb.php`) into your theme ( `/theme_name/woocommerce/global/` ) and there add the code to include the link before the output loop starts. I only do it for product category, tag and detail but you can add other conditionals if you like.

```
<?php
/**
 * Shop breadcrumb
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.3.0
 * @see         woocommerce_breadcrumb()
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

if ( $breadcrumb ) {

    // add shop home url to breadcrumbs
    if( is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product() ) {
        $shop_page_id = wc_get_page_id( 'shop' );
        $shop_home_arr = array( get_the_title($shop_page_id), get_permalink($shop_page_id));

        // insert to breadcrumbs array on second position
        array_splice($breadcrumb, 1, 0, array($shop_home_arr));
    }

    echo $wrap_before;

    foreach ( $breadcrumb as $key => $crumb ) {

        echo $before;

        if ( ! empty( $crumb[1] ) && sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
            echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $crumb[1] ) . '">' . esc_html( $crumb[0] ) . '</a>';
        } else {
            echo esc_html( $crumb[0] );
        }

        echo $after;

        if ( sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
            echo $delimiter;
        }
    }
    echo $wrap_after;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be done a lot easier. It is just necessary to change the permalinks settings accordingly - as mentioned on github at the [issue 3145](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/3145#issuecomment-18552561):

> Meet this criteria:
>
> ```
> // If permalinks contain the shop page in the URI prepend the breadcrumb with shop 
> if (
>   $shop_page_id
>   && strstr( $permalinks['product_base'], '/' . $shop_page->post_name )
>   && get_option( 'page_on_front' ) !== $shop_page_id
>  ) {
>    $prepend = $before 
>      . '<a href="' . get_permalink( $shop_page ) . '">' 
>      . $shop_page->post_title . '</a> ' 
>      . $after . $delimiter;
>  }
> ```
>
> Otherwise its never prepended.

To apply this one has to go to:

> → WordPress Backend → Settings → Permalinks

And set the woocommerce permalinks settings to one of these:

- Shop Base
- Shop Base With Category
- Custom Base

If the latter is used the slug »/shop/...« has to be prepended.

There is an [issue 6584](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/6584):

> Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 't' in wc-core-functions.php on line 533

Which for example occures if the »Custom Base« looks like this: »/shop/product/...«. There is a [commit](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/commit/4d3fbaa9e07e82939ec7e25b41237af672ab0d99) that fixed it, which is available in master, but not 2.2.8.

The slug part shop can be replaced by something else too, for example something localized.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved without code, but will require you to change **product permalink** settings to "**Shop base with category**":

1. Go to **Dashboard** -> **Settings** -> **Permalinks**
2. Scroll down to "**Product Permalinks**"
3. Select "**Shop base with category**"
4. **Save Changes**

Breadcrumbs will now display the "Shop": **Home > Shop > Category > Subcategory > Product**

However, as we are changing the permalinks, your website URL structure will also change to the new setting: `https://yoursite.com/shop/category/product/`. This means manually inserted links will need to be changed as the old URL links do not exist now.